# Update query is not working in java swing

Tags: java, swing, ms-access-2007, database-connection

I am working on a project "Hospital Management System" in java swing.

On update page there are various text field, text area, combo box and accordingly various columns in MS Access table named `patient`.

There are only three columns in the database which accepts numeric value and they are `roomno`, `contact` and `patid` fetching their values from `textField_2`, `textField_3` and `comboBox_2`.

Now the problem is whenever I press `Update` button after filling all information it is showing an error message like

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data
>   type mismatch in criteria expression.

While executing `ps.executeUpdate()`.

I have checked it 100 time but it is still showing the error message. Please help and thanks in advance.

```
if (ae.getActionCommand()=="UPDATE")
        {
            str1=textField_2.getText();             // Room no.
            str2=textField_3.getText();             // Contact no.
            str3=""+comboBox_2.getSelectedItem();   //ID

            s1=textField.getText();     //name
            s2=textField_7.getText();   //address   
            s4=textArea.getText();      //history
            s3=""+comboBox.getSelectedItem();       // blood group
            s5=""+comboBox_1.getSelectedItem();     //type of room          

            s7=textField_4.getText();   //  date of addmission(doa)
            s8=textField_5.getText();   //  date of birth(dob)
            s9=textArea_2.getText();        //  current problem
            s10=textField_6.getText();  //  doctor
            if (str1.equals("") || str2.equals(""))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PLEASE COMPLETE THE FORM.");
            }
            else if (s1.equals("") || s2.equals("") || s4.equals("") || s5.equals("") || s6.equals("") || s7.equals("") || s8.equals("") || s9.equals("") || s10.equals(""))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PLEASE COMPLETE THE FORM.,");
            }
            else 
            {           
                try
                {                   
                    if (!(str1.matches("[0-9]+")) && !(str2.matches("[0-9]+")))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ROOM NO. AND CONTACT MUST CONTAIN DIGITS.");
                    }
                    else if (!(str1.matches("[0-9]+")))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ROOM NO. MUST CONTAIN DIGITS.");
                    }
                    else if (!(str2.matches("[0-9]+")))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"CONTACT MUST CONTAIN DIGITS.");
                    }   
                    else if (str2.length() != 10)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PLEASE ENTER VALID MOBILE NUMBER.");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Connection con;
                        PreparedStatement ps;
                        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:hos_man");

                        ps=con.prepareStatement("update patient set sname='"+s1+"', address='"+s2+"', bloodgrp='"+s3+"', history='"+s4+"', roomtype='"+s5+"', roomno="+str1+", contact="+str2+", doa='"+s7+"', gender='"+s6+"', dob='"+s8+"', problem='"+s9+"', doctor='"+s10+"' where patid="+str3);

                        ps.executeUpdate();  //ERROR MESSAGE

                        con.close();
                        ps.close();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DATA MODIFIED SUCCESSFULLY.");

                        textField_2.setText("");
                        textField_3.setText("");            

                        textField.setText("");
                        textField_7.setText("");            
                        textArea.setText("");           

                        comboBox.setSelectedItem("A-ve");
                        comboBox_1.setSelectedItem("Deluxe");                   

                        rdbtnMale.setSelected(true);            

                        textField_4.setText("");
                        textField_5.setText("");
                        textArea_2.setText("");
                        textField_6.setText("");
                        comboBox_2.setSelectedIndex(0);
                    }
                }               
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception="+e);
                }                               
            }                       
        }
```

Comment: Start by using [`PreparedStatement`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: I didn't get it. Please elaborate.

Comment: Read the linked tutorial, you're not using `PreapredStatement` the way it's intended...

Comment: Ok, I got your point. I know there are several ways for database connectivity. But the point is why my code is showing error message while the another update program(with small database) is getting executed successfully. As I am a beginner, it's not easy for me to adopt several methods. If you can correct this code, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know it's the numeric values that are giving you the error, the problem would also be with the date values?  Simple solution would be to set up a test and test each parameter individually, gradually appending a new parameter until it breaks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PreparedStatement is used for giving dynamic parameter to query.Instead of using Prepared statement, use Statement.

If you want to use Prepared Statement then

```
ps=con.prepareStatement("update patient set sname=?, address=?, bloodgrp=?, history=?, roomtype=?, roomno=?, contact=?, doa=?.................);
ps.setString(1,s1);

...
..
.

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, but It will be great if you write complete query for me. I tried to update my program according to this method but it is not working. Please help.

Comment: ps=con.prepareStatement("update patient set sname=?, address=?, bloodgrp=?, history=?, roomtype=?, roomno=?, contact=?, doa=?, gender=?, dob=?, problem=?, doctor=? where patid=?");


if still error comes ,do post your error.

Comment: Problem solved. But as I am a beginner I am in a big dilemma that which method should I use. The first which I wrote in my question and I have been using that method since starting or the second method that you told me today. Please help.

Comment: Please read this(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-statements.htm) to understand which interface to use when.